# clear datapoints from bokeh plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm still somewhat new to Bokeh, and I've run into a problem I haven't been able to solve.

I have a Bokeh plot visualizing some streaming data in two separate figures. For various reasons the users of the plot may want to clear the two plots of the current datapoints upon clicking a button.

What would be the good way to clear the figures? I am yet to come upon a good solution.

My code looks something like:

```py
#Defining plots
plot_data = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[],y=[],z=[]))

p = figure(plot_height = 600, plot_width = 800, 
               x_axis_label = 'X', 
               y_axis_label = 'Y')
p2 = figure(plot_height = 600, plot_width = 800, 
               x_axis_label = 'X', 
               y_axis_label = 'Z')

doc = curdoc()
```

The data source is getting updated in an async loop:

```py
async def loop():
    while True:
        data = await socket.recv_pyobj()
        new_data = get_last_data(data)
        #update ColumnDataSource
        doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(update,new_data))

doc.add_root(column(gridplot([p,p2], plot_width=1000)))

try:        
    testloop = IOLoop.current()
    testloop.spawn_callback(loop)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    testloop.close()
```

and the `ColumnDataSource` is getting updated through the following function when new datapoints appear in the stream (parsed as a dataframe)

```py
def update(new_data):
    input_data = dict(x=new_data['x'], y=new_data['y'], z=new_data['z'])
    plot_data.stream(input_data, rollover=500)
```

My initial idea for clearing the figures through a button click is the following:

```py
#Defining button for clearing plot
button = Button(label="CLEAR PLOT", button_type="danger")
def clear_plot(event):
    plot_data = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[],y=[],z=[]))
button.on_event(ButtonClick,clear_plot)
```

This is not working, and if I understand the `stream` method correctly, that is at the heart of the problem, as new data is continuously getting appended to the source and the above `clear_plot` function will not really clear the stream data source. How would one go about clearing the stream data source such that the figures are cleared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assigning a new value to `plot_data`, you're just changing the variable itself. Anything that got the reference to the previous value of `plot_data` will still have that old reference.
Instead, try changing the `data` attribute of the data source:

```
def clear_plot(event):
    plot_data.data = {k: [] for k in plot_data.data}
```